# MySQL JOIN and DATE comparison/manipulation

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, phpmyadmin

Consider the following MySQL tables:

*APPLICATIONS* (contains all applications by all users)

```
unique_id |  user_id  |  date_of_application  |  date_ended  | status
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1            user_a          2010-09-09          2010-12-24     Ended
2            user_a          2011-03-03          2011-06-06     Ended
3            user_a          2011-08-08          2011-10-10     Ended
4            user_b          2011-10-01                         Active
```

*ITEM_TRANSACTIONS* (contains all item transactions by all users)

```
user_id |  item_id  |  quantity_ordered  |  date_requested  |  date_received
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
user_a      item_a            20              2011-10-01         2011-10-02
user_a      item_b            10              2011-10-01         2011-10-02
user_b      item_a            30              2011-10-05         2011-10-10
user_b      item_b            30              2011-10-05         2011-10-10
```

*ITEMS*

```
item_id |  item_name  |  item_price
------------------------------------
item_a      Item AA         500
item_b      Item BB         1000
```

So far I have the following query that already takes the the sum of the values of the item prices **distinct per user**.

However, what I need in addition to this is that SELECT should only cover (compute for the sum) of those **item transactions** that its user's status has **Ended** and that application being the **latest** one.

To reiterate, the **applications** and **item_transactions** tables will contain several records by the same user over time, what should be covered (SELECTED) are those transactions under the latest application (status **Ended**) only.

```
SELECT
    item_po.poid,
    SUM(item_transactions.quantity_ordered) AS qtysum,
    item_transactions.item_id,
    item_transactions.quantity_ordered,

    items.item_id,
    items.item_price,

    applications.user_id,
    applications.status

FROM
    items

WHERE
    applications.status='Ended'

GROUP BY
    item_transactions.user_id
```

Comment: +1 for exemplary format. but you fail to tell us the general purpose of your query. can you describe in every day language what it is for and what the result should be?

Comment: Would you please tell me the expected result that you want.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Hmm how should I put this... perhaps it's like saying I want to compute for the sales of a given company based on the date parameters provided (in my case it's date_of_application and date_ended). Also taking account that only the latest application should be considered. In my case user_b is out of the equation since his status is Active at the moment. Err I hope that makes it clear =P

Comment: @Arif I though I got that covered =P Regardless, based on the above tables, what I wanted to do should give me the : (**sum of the price and sum of the quantity of all the items**) by (**the user in which his application status has 'Ended'**) and that (**those item_transactions have occurred within that specific span of application**). The first one I already covered using the posted query. In addition (**we should only compute for the latest/last application of the same raiser**)

Comment: Hello, Where is ** item_po.poid **..? you have not detailed  ** item_po ** table over here...Please explain.

Comment: what you have done was, you have done the sum of quantity only,not the price...please check and explain if i'm wrong..Thanx.

Comment: @Chandresh My bad that should be item_transactions.user_id, not item_po.poid

Answer (score 0):

To select only the last ended application for each user, you can use a subquery to select the IDs of those applications and join the applications table with that subquery.  Assuming that application IDs are ordered chronologically:

```sql
SELECT
  item_po.poid,
  SUM(item_transactions.quantity_ordered) AS qtysum,
  item_transactions.item_id,
  item_transactions.quantity_ordered,
  items.item_id,
  items.item_price,
  applications.user_id,
  applications.status   
FROM
  applications
  NATURAL JOIN (
    SELECT
      MAX(unique_id) AS unique_id
    FROM applications
    WHERE status = 'Ended'
    GROUP BY user_id
  ) AS foo
  /* ... other joins here ... */
```

However, I couldn't figure out from your description exactly how the transactions should be joined to the applications.  I *assume* you probably want something like this:

```sql
  JOIN item_transactions
    ON date_requested BETWEEN date_of_application AND date_ended
  NATURAL JOIN items
```

but I'm not sure about the exact join criteria.  (For example, what if the item was requested during the application period but delivered after its end?  Or requested before but delivered during the application period?)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.

```
SELECT

    SUM(Tran.quantity_ordered) AS qtysum,
    Tran.item_id,
    Tran.quantity_ordered,

    I.item_id,
    I.item_price,

    A.user_id,
    A.status

FROM
    items as I,applications as A, item_transactions AS Tran

WHERE
    A.status='Ended'

GROUP BY
    Tran.user_id

    ORDER BY A.unique_id DESC 

LIMIT 0,1
```

If you are looking for only one latest record then you need to use **LIMIT 0,1** otherwise its working without that..i think this would be helpful to you.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

how about if you try this one:

```
SELECT
    item_po.poid,
    SUM(item_transactions.quantity_ordered) AS qtysum,
    item_transactions.item_id,
    item_transactions.quantity_ordered,

    items.item_id,
    items.item_price,

    applications.user_id,
    applications.status

FROM
    items

WHERE
    applications.status='Ended'
AND applications.date_of_application = (SELECT MAX(date_of_application) FROM applications
WHERE status='Ended' LIMIT 0, 1)

GROUP BY
    item_transactions.user_id
```

Since you need the latest application you should get the latest date of all the ended applications no matter when it did ended, but I'm having doubt on this statement "that its user's status has Ended and that application being the latest one." cause I was thinking you might be saying that once a transaction has ended that will turn the transaction as the latest one no matter when it did started being there on the record if that is the case instead of using the date_of_application attribute you may somehow use date_ended instead.

I hope this helps.

:)